# Inserting and deleting node in Doubly Linked list C++

Tags: c++, insert, doubly-linked-list, erase

I'm having an issue while creating a circular doubly linked list. My code seems to work fine when adding a new node. It also works when deleting every other node. The problem arises when I attempt to erase 2 continuous nodes. I've gone through my code for the past 2 days, and while I did find some errors none corrected the issue.

```
void LinkedList::insert(Node *newnode, Node * pred)
{
    Node *after;

    if ((empty()) && (pred != head))
    {
        cout << "*&$MU##\n";
    }
    else
    {
        after = pred->next;

        newnode->next = pred->next;
        newnode->pred = pred;
        pred->next->pred = newnode;
        pred->next = newnode;

        listSize++;
    }
}

void LinkedList::erase(Node *pred)
{   
    Node *actual; //actual node to be deleted
    Node *after; //node after the node to be deleted
    if (!empty())
    {
        actual = pred->next;

        after = actual->next;
        pred->next = after;
        after->pred = pred;
        actual->next = '\0';
        actual->pred = '\0';

        listSize--;
    }
}
```

Command to add node is as follows: mylist.insert(newnode, pred)
Command to erase a node is: erase(pred)

I believe the problem arises when I erase a node as my functions sets the pred and next values to NULL. When I call the erase function once more with the following node, it cannot longer do the following `actual = pred->next; after = actual->next;` because the pred and next for that node were already set to NULL by the previous command.

Any help will be appreciated.

I've decided to add the whole code for my LinkedList.cpp in case the problem lies there.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Node.h"
#include "LinkedList.h"

LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
    Node * hnode = new Node('?');
    head = hnode;
    listSize = 0;
    first = head;
    first->next = first;
    //first->pred = first;
}
bool LinkedList::empty()//O(1)
{
    if (first->next == first)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

void LinkedList::insert(Node *newnode, Node * pred)
{
    Node *after;

    if ((empty()) && (pred != head))
    {
        cout << "*&$MU##\n";
    }
    else
    {
        after = pred->next;

        newnode->next = pred->next;
        newnode->pred = pred;
        pred->next->pred = newnode;
        pred->next = newnode;

        listSize++;
    }
}
void LinkedList::erase(Node *pred)
{   
    Node *actual; //actual node to be deleted
    Node *after; //node after the node to be deleted
    if (!empty())
    {
        actual = pred->next;
        after = actual->next;

        pred->next = after;
        after->pred = pred;
        actual->next = '\0';
        actual->pred = '\0';

        listSize--;
    }
}

void LinkedList::display()
{
    Node * current_node;
    current_node = first;
    do
    {
        cout << current_node->data << " ";
        current_node = current_node->next;
    } while (current_node != first);
    cout << listSize<< '\n';
}
```

Comment: `'\0'` isn't `NULL`; your function won't work properly if `pred` is the only node in the list; and you don't have any handling to update `head` in case it's the one that's erased. Other than that I can't see anything obviously wrong (although it's unusual for an erase function to erase the following node rather than the one you pass in). What actually goes wrong?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to call the erase function?

Comment: @JonathanPotter I have that piece of code inside and if statement that checks to see if the list is empty.

Comment: @TheDark If I type the following commands 'mylist.erase(n4) mylist.erase(n5)' The first will execute with out a problem but the second one will not.

Comment: If `n5` is the node after `n4` then your code would have removed `n5` from the list when you call `erase(n4)`. It would also have cleared its pointers. If you want to erase two nodes next to each other you would use `erase(n4);erase(n4);`. Note: It is a bit odd to have the erase function erase the next node, rather than the one you pass in.